# WRT1900AC and network monitoring

Tags: wifi

I just set up a new home network for my mom using a Linksys WRT1900AC router, and it has 24 devices on it right now, yet will have more soon.

I can see the network map through linksyssmartwifi.com, yet I would like a log of everything that gets on the network and I want some kind of sniffer to monitor and analyze the traffic.

This router does not have SNMP traffic or netflow sensors.

Does anyone know software for monitoring a home network that is compatible with the Linksys WRT1900AC?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this with the stock firmware. You should change over to openWRT to do what you want.

Download the .iso from [here](https://github.com/wrt1900ac/opensource/releases). (I recently installed the Attitude Adjustment iso). Go into troubleshooting (I think) and on the right hand side it says update firmware. Just point it to the ISO and you will have a much more flexible router.

From here you have great control over logging, firewalls, interfaces etc. iptables will be installed by default and you can use that to do almost anything you need.

See the [openWRT](https://openwrt.org/) page for more.

From here you can set up [port mirroring with iptables](http://blog.goddchen.de/2009/03/port-mirroring-span-port-monitor-port-with-iptables/) and send it to an IDS/IPS like [snort](https://www.snort.org/) or [suricata](http://suricata-ids.org/). If you want to use a central logging system (to forward the logs from the IDS you might use something like [ossec](http://www.ossec.net/)). Note that all of these tools come with [security onion](http://blog.securityonion.net/p/securityonion.html) if you prefer ubuntu.